# Select multiple rows in UITableView with dragging finger

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I would like to ask if it is possible to select multiple cells by dragging my finger on the cells I want to select. For example when you are cropping a picture, you are dragging a line with your finger and I want to have a similar effect.

I can also consider using other UI elements rather than a UITableView, open to suggestions.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: this'd mean table view wont be scrollable. would that be fine?

Comment: @calvinBhai : OP mentioned other UI elements will also be fine...not only for tableview.

Comment: better to clarify, than assume, give answer, and see a comment saying thats not exactly what the OP wanted :)

Comment: Thank you for your interest :) Yes it won't be scrollable in that case. Dou you have any offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a transparent(`view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`) overlay view above the table view when you want to select.

In this transparent view, you should set up a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, and by watching events of this recogniser, especially the events for `Began`, `Changed`, `Ended` and `Cancelled`. The target object would know the range to select.